# Brackets around negative numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting

How would I go about placing a negative value e.g. -0.75 in brackets in excel: (-0.75). I have changed the custom format of the cell to **(General)** but negative numbers are being rendered as -(0.75). I need a fancy trick to bring that negative **inside** the brackets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For me it's working as intended. Maybe it's a setting issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a separate format for negative numbers seems to do the trick

`(General);(-General)`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a

```
'
```

before the value like

```
'(-0.75)
```

Comment: Ah, but now Excel removes the parentheses :( Extraordinary.

Comment: Weird, that trick should render the cell contents as is. :)